# Applying K-means to MFCC Coefficients for ASR

Tags: speech-recognition, k-means, speech, mfcc

I have divided my audio signal into 20ms frame with 10ms overlap. As a result I have 500 frames. I have computed the MFCC coefficients for each frame. I want to do Vector Quantization for each frame using the K-MEAN algorithm.

I have 16 MFCC Coefficients per frame (vector length: 16). Now K-MEAN Requires 2 Vectors to form the cluster diagram (one along X,one along Y), however I have only one vector (the 16 MFCC coefficients per frame).

So how do I proceed? Do I take adjacent frames and apply K-mean to the adjacent frames?

Answer (score 1):

> Now K-MEAN Requires 2 Vectors to form the cluster diagram(one along X,one along Y)

This is not true, kmeans algorithm can cluster arbitrary number of vectors.

> So how do I proceed? Do I take adjacent frames and apply K-mean TO THE ADJACENT FRAMES?

You have 500 vectors, you apply kmeans for all of them.

> For eg., in MATLAB , the input vector X must be of the dimension 2xM matrix for the kmean function;

There is no such requirement

> Which Vectors Do I choose to form the clusters in the K-MEAN?  HOW do I APPLY kmeans TO each vector?

Again, you take all vectors as in [documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html).

```
     [idx,C] = kmeans(X,num_clusters);
```

X is a matrix of 500x13.

> After seeing a bunch of tutorials, Usually the i/p is two data sets (X1,X2) for a 2-D Kmeans space.

If you are about documentation above, x1 and x2 are examples of the clusters. There is also a cluster x3.

> My doubt is in the case of MFCC, what should be my X1,X2?

There will be clusters corresponding to phonemes for example. If you have 20 phonemes you cluster on 20 centroids and each will correspond to phoneme. You can also cluster on 256 centroids if you have enough data, then clusters will correspond to abstract common feature values in speech.

Comment: I'm sorry if my doubts sound a bit absurd. My main doubt is HOW do I apply K-MEAN to the 13X500 MFCC coefficients I have. For eg., in MATLAB , the input vector X must be of the dimension 2xM matrix for the kmean function; Which Vectors Do I choose to form the clusters in the K-MEAN?HOW do I APPLY kmeans TO each vector? I would really appreciate if you could take the time to explain such an elementary doubt.Thanks a lot!

Comment: After seeing a bunch of tutorials, Usually the i/p is two data sets (X1,X2)  for a 2-D Kmeans space. My doubt is in the case of MFCC, what should be my X1,X2?

Comment: I replied in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibility that i see here :
1) you want to quantize your mfcc features ( seperate the features into amplitude groups of strong, medium, and small for example ). In this case you want to run per frame and insert the vector of features as each feature being a single point for the k-means algorithm. If you absolutely must (and you don't) have an mx2 input vector just add 1 to each feature ( MFCCs = [MFCCS, ones(size(MFCCs,1),1)]; )

2) You want to find groups of frames which are similar to one another. In this case, each one of your "points" for the kmeans algorithm is all of the MFCC features for a single frame. This is what Nikolay is talking about.

Cheers,
Dan